# How to remove 'root' from iteration path in TFS queries

Tags: tfs, iteration, tfs-workitem

In Team foundation server I use Iterations / Areas. However when I run queries and select Iteration path as a column it always contains the 'root' iteration i.e. the name of the project.

Is there a way how to get rid of it? It takes so much space (I unwisely chose long project name) and adds no extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops - I just finally got around to checking this for myself instead of going from memory.  You can rename all the nodes, except the root.  My mistake. The root gets replaced by the name of the project.  Sorry for misleading you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The 'root' is a standard part of the path and can't be removed.

You could always rename it if you want a shorter name. It doesn't have to match the name of the project - that's only done so that you have a default value for the root after  you first create the project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having some difficulties actually find where to change it. Should I ask our TFS admin to use his stuff?

Comment: Assuming you permission, right click the Project in Team Explorer.  You'll see an option for Areas and Iterations.  Go in to that, and you should be on the Areas tab.  From there it's just a case of clicking the root node to put it into edit mode, change the values and you're done.